# Basic Ruby Exercise - Method and If

Tags: ruby

I am doing a Ruby exercise, but I can't figure out what is wrong.  I need to modify the `suma` method so my tests both return true.

I'm not allowed to add another if, or else, remove code or modify arguments.  Am I missing something?

```
def suma(a, b)
  "#{a} es mayor que #{b}" if a > b
  "#{a} no es mayor que #{b}"
end

#test
p suma(10, 5) == "10 es mayor que 5"
p suma(4, 23) == "4 no es mayor que 23"
```

Comment: Ruby returns always last expression from method. In this case the second sentence is still the last on in the execution chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `return` in the first conditional.

```
def suma(a, b)
  return "#{a} es mayor que #{b}" if a > b
  "#{a} no es mayor que #{b}"
end
```

Ruby by default will return the last statement in a method, but it allows for early returns.  Since you want to return early if `a > b`, you have to tell Ruby as much.  Otherwise, it will execute the line and default to the last statement in the method for its return.